# How to get objects saved in JSON format and put to a list or map in the controller

Tags: java, api, rest, controller

I use remote REST API:
[http://bank.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/**{table}/{code}**/](http://bank.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/**%7Btable%7D/%7Bcode%7D**/)

I want to download 3 items simultaneously entering the `**{code}**` codes of 3 currencies: USD, EUR, GBP like String   **{code}** of **3** currencies: **USD, EUR, GBP**.

The **{table}** parameter is constant and does not change   C

```
   private final String URI_CURRENCY_PATH_ID = "http://bank.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/C/{code}";
     
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
     
    // Using RestTemplate
     
    
     
   //"C/{code}"
    Map <String, String> params = new HashMap <String, String> ();
    params.put ("C", "USD");
    Currency currency = restTemplate.getForObject (URI_CURRENCY_PATH_ID, Currency.class, params);
```

If i use POSTMAN i get 3 objects:

```
{"table":"C","currency":"dolar amerykański","code":"USD","rates":[{"no":"186/C/NBP/2021","effectiveDate":"2021-09-24","bid":3.8897,"ask":3.9683}]}

{"table":"C","currency":"euro","code":"EUR","rates":[{"no":"186/C/NBP/2021","effectiveDate":"2021-09-24","bid":4.5664,"ask":4.6586}]}

{"table":"C","currency":"funt szterling","code":"GBP","rates":[{"no":"186/C/NBP/2021","effectiveDate":"2021-09-24","bid":5.3426,"ask":5.4506}]}
```

Is it possible to get 3 currencies at the same time using List or Map as direct save

Maybe someone will help as best to solve this problem.

Comment: That Postman response isn't valid JSON, is it from a single request or three seperate requests?

Comment: Hi Davies .The answer is three separate requests

Answer (score 0):

From your API, it looks like it only accepts a single argument. In that case, you can not call the API with multiple arguments in one go and have the response back which you are looking for. However, you can call the API in parallel with different arguments so you won't have to wait till one API call responds. Below is the code snippet which you can refer to call the API in parallel which essentially solves your problem.

```
@Service
public class RestService {

    private final String URI_CURRENCY_PATH_ID = "http://bank.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/C/{code}";

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public void callApi() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        CompletableFuture<Currency> apiCall1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callRestApi(map), executor).thenApply(jsonNode -> callRestApi(jsonNode));
        CompletableFuture<Currency> apiCall2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callRestApi(map), executor).thenApply(jsonNode -> callRestApi(jsonNode));
        CompletableFuture<Currency> apiCall3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callRestApi(map), executor).thenApply(jsonNode -> callRestApi(jsonNode));
        List<Currency> result = Stream.of(apiCall1, apiCall2, apiCall3)
                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private JsonNode callRestApi(final Map<String, String> params) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject (URI_CURRENCY_PATH_ID, JsonNode.class, params);
    }

    private Currency callRestApi(final JsonNode jsonNode) {
        // deserialize it and return your Currency object
        return new Currency(); // just for example
    }

    // Keep it somewhere in Model package (here just for example)
    private class Currency {
        // define your arguments
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi rishi . I sent my class currency implementation.